# Xampp-Lampp fedora linux localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, xampp, lampp

I have php project on Win and Linux it works normally on linux but it gives this error when I run in the browerser on Linux `localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` When I delete these lines of code which is instace of a class **it works normally**

```
require 'controller/youtubedata.php';

$analyziz = new Exttractdata();

$analyziz->youtubedata();
```

from the index.php it works a little I have some in controller/youtubedata.php about Youtube Data API is could be the problem?
this the tree of controller

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/seosystem/controller
├── controller.php
└── youtubedata.php
```

This the tree of the project

```
├── adsapi_php.ini
├── bootstrap
├── controller
├── google-ads-php
├── grpc
└── index.php
```

Comment: Check your log files. Error 500 is the webbrowsers error, ment for users; developers/administrators can see the real error in the logfiles (either php logs or httpd logs).

Comment: Thanks it was hideous error I was writing require `'controller\controller.php';` from windows with backslah after changing to forwardslash / it works and this after I saw the log